# Mapping a pandas dataframe to a n-dimensional array, where each dimension corresponds to one of the x columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with columns `x0 x1 x2 x3 x4` and `y0 y1 y2 y3 y4`.

First ten rows:

```py
    Id  x0  x1  x2  x3  x4  y0  y1  y2  y3  y4
0   0   -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    268035854.2037072   0.94956508069182    3520.7568220782514  -412868933.038522   242572043.87727848
1   1   -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -4.5    268035883.40390667  0.94956508069182    3482.0382462663074  -412868933.038522   242572043.87727848
2   2   -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -4.0    268035901.1170006   0.94956508069182    3443.3196704543634  -412868933.038522   242572043.87727848
3   3   -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -3.5    268035911.8642905   0.94956508069182    3404.6010946424194  -412868933.038522   242572043.87727848
4   4   -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -3.0    268035918.38904288  0.94956508069182    3365.882518830476   -412868933.038522   242572043.87727848
5   5   -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -2.5    268035922.35671327  0.94956508069182    3327.163943018532   -412868933.038522   242572043.87727848
6   6   -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -2.0    268035924.7800574   0.94956508069182    3288.445367206588   -412868933.038522   242572043.87727848
7   7   -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -1.5    268035926.27763835  0.94956508069182    3249.726791394644   -412868933.038522   242572043.87727848
8   8   -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -1.0    268035927.2317166   0.94956508069182    3211.0082155827004  -412868933.038522   242572043.87727848
9   9   -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -5.0    -0.5    268035927.8858225   0.94956508069182    3172.2896397707564  -412868933.038522   242572043.87727848
```

I did this:

```
values = df_train[['y0', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']].values
values.shape
```

I now have `shape (4084101, 5)`

I would like to have shape `(21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 5)` (so that the first shape is `x0`, the second `x1`, like if we had a 5D graph). Basically, it should be `values[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` to access the tuple `(y0, y1, y2, y3, y4)` corresponding to `x0=-4.5`, `x1=-5`, ..., `x4=-5`.

21 because values go from -5 to 5 for the `x0, ..., x4` with step `0.5`
and 5 because `y0, y1, y2, y3, y4`
I did `values = values.reshape(21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 5)`
But when I do `values[1][0][0][0][0]`, I expected to have the value corresponding to `x1=-4.5, x2=-5, ..., x4=-5`  but I don't.

One bad idea that I had (complexity wise) was to make a dictionary in which keys are tuples (x0, x1, x2, x3, x4) and attributes the index where to find the y values.
And then fill a `np.zeros((21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 5))` dataframe.

```py
# Get the values
values = df_train[['y0', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']].values

# Create a dictionary to map the x0, x1, x2, x3, x4 values to indices
grid = {}
for i, row in df_train.iterrows():
    x0, x1, x2, x3, x4 = [int((x + 5) / 0.5) for x in [row['x0'], row['x1'], row['x2'], row['x3'], row['x4']]]
    grid[(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4)] = i

# Create the reshaped array
reshaped_values = np.zeros((21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 5))
for key, index in grid.items():
    reshaped_values[key[0]][key[1]][key[2]][key[3]][key[4]] = values[index]
```

but it takes almost a minute on my computer ... and looks like the worst idea ever.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If I replace y0..y4 by x0..x4 (same shape) and I use `arr[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` it returns `array([-4.5, -5. , -5. , -5. , -5. ])` so it's what you expect?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what object is `arr`?

Comment: Sorry, it's the same as `values` but with x values. `values[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` gives me `array([-4.5, -5. , -5. , -5. , -5. ])`

Comment: What you say doesn't work for me: https://i.imgur.com/Xfhz4aJ.png

Comment: But that pinpoints exactly my misunderstanding about this whole thing, why does `arr[1, 0, 0, 0, 0]` give me `[-5.  -4.5 -5.  -5.  -5. ]` which I'm having A LOT of trouble understanding.

Comment: Are you sure your dataframe is sorted by x keys?

Comment: It wasn't oh my god, that was stupid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works but I think your dataframe is not sorted

```
df_train = df_train.sort_values(['x0', 'x1', 'x2', 'x3', 'x4'])

values = df_train[['y0', 'y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']].values
```